# Inno-setup: function not found?

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to build a script using Pascal scripting to return the name of a folder (but I want later to use the same function for wider results).
My scrip is here:

```
;This is a test script
#define MySourceDir "D:\Temp\InnoTestSrc"
#define MyDestDir "D:\Temp\InnoTest"

[Setup]
DefaultDirName={#MyDestDir}
DisableDirPage=no
AppName="MyTestApp"
AppVersion=1

[Code]
function GetMyConstant(Param: String): String;
var
    strConst: string;

begin
    strConst := '{#' + Param + '}';
    MsgBox(strConst, mbInformation, MB_OK);
    Result := expandconstant(strConst);
end;

function GetDataDir(Param: String): String;
begin
  { Return the selected DataDir }
  Result := 'DummyString';
end;

[Files]
Source: {#MySourceDir}\TestFile.pdf; DestDir: {code: GetDataDir}
```

However, when I try to compile it, I get

Compile Error!
Line: 29
Error: Required function or procedure ' GetDataDir' not found.

I am trying to understand why the compiler cannot find the function, but I do not understand.
Any help to my (probably obvious) error would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it work if you do

```
Source: "{#MySourceDir}\TestFile.pdf"; DestDir: "{code:GetDataDir}"
```

instead? I think it does. Indeed, you should listen to the compiler, which says that there is no function called `<space>GetDataDir`. Of course there is not! Your function is called `GetDataDir`!

Comment: OK! You win! I apologise for wasting your time with such a stupid mistake!!!! I did not look well enough to the error message! Thanks a lot for taking the time to correct me!

Comment: This is clearly a InnoSetup bug. Functions can't start with space. The function name must be trimmed by the compiler first.